# The return type 'Widget?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using consumer widget to avoid re-rendering before null safety it works fine... But when I upgrade provider package to it gives me an error which I mentioned above it is not accepting `ListView.builder()` and says that The return type `Widget?` isn't a `Widget`, as required by the closure's context

```
Consumer<GreatPlaces>(
        child: Center(
          child: const Text(
            'Got no places yet, start adding some',
          ),
        ),
        builder: (ctx, greatPlaces, ch) => greatPlaces.items.length <= 0
            ? ch
            : ListView.builder(          ***//Here I got error***
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Center(),
                itemCount: 5,
              ),
      ),
```

Comment: please add more information about what you are trying to do

Comment: I am using consumer widget to avoid re-rendering before null safety it works fine... But when I upgrade provider package to it gives me an error which I mentioned above it is not accepting ListView.builder() and says that **The return type 'Widget?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context**

Comment: In Flutter's null-safety update, `Widget?` is nullable and `Widget` is non-nullable. I'm guessing that `ListView.builder` can sometimes be null and that this is what's causing your issue. Try replacing `ListView.builder`... with a `Container()` and rerunning your code. If the error disappears then you know what the problem is and you need to define your widget without the `.builder` constructor

Comment: I define ListView without builder, it gives me same error

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use null-assert `!` operation on `ch!`

```dart
 data.state.length <= 0
          ? child!
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(),
              itemCount: 4,
            );
```

Comment: your solution solve my problem on this code : body: Consumer<GreatPlaces>(
        builder: (ctx, greatPlaces, ch) =>
            greatPlaces.items.length <= 0 ? ch! : ListView(),
        child: Center(
          child: const Text('Got no places yet , start adding some!'),
        ),
      ),

Comment: For me too solved

Answer (score 1):

Use below same sample solution ;

```
  body: Consumer<GreatPlaces>(
    child: const Center(
      child: Text('Got no places yet, start adding some!'),
    ),
    builder: (ctx, greatPlaces, ch) => greatPlaces.items.isEmpty
        ? ch!
        : ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: FileImage(
                  greatPlaces.items[index].image,
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(greatPlaces.items[index].title),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            itemCount: greatPlaces.items.length,
          ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```dart
Consumer<GreatPlaces>(
  child: Center(
    child: const Text(
      'Got no places yet, start adding some',
    ),
  ),
  builder: (ctx, greatPlaces, ch) => greatPlaces.items.length <= 0
      ? ch ?? Container() // You change Container to other widget
      : ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Center(),
          itemCount: 5,
        ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding nullcheck to the ch

```
body:Consumer<GreatPlaces>(
        child:Center(
        child: Text('Got no places yet, strat adding some!'),
        ),
        builder:(ctx,greatPlaces,ch)=>greatPlaces.items.length<=0 ? 
          ch!:ListView.builder(
          itemCount: greatPlaces.items.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx,i)=>ListTile(),
      ),
     ));
```